# moving the source folder crashes my app

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have a weird problem .. maybe the solution is simple but i'm just a newbie in iPhone app development

the problem is:
i have created xcode iphone project , tested is and it was running well.
copied the project folder to my desktop . opened the project from the new location . tried to run the app, the simulator opens and the application crashes!!

any solution ? is there anything i need to clean in the project
 files ?

Comment: which error do your Console display on crash?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using absolute paths in your code ?
Maybe something with additional resources you added before.
Try to look first for those kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode, Go through every file in your project that resides within your project folder, right click on them in the hierarchy tree to the left, select get info, go to the general tab and change the Path Type to "Relative to Project"

Answer (score 0):

What sort of project did you create?

I created a simple View-based application in my Documents folder. I built and ran it in the simulator successfully. I then quit Xcode, dragged the project folder to the desktop. I reopened the project and ran it successfully in the simulator again.

Did you make any changes at all to the project? I can't repeat what you've experienced. Is there anything different between what we did?

How about creating your project on the desktop in the first place? Does that work?

Are you running as an administrator account? Sometimes there are problems with Xcode if you run in an account where the user isn't a member of the Dev group.